# IMX28 - I2C - Failed to send SELECT command!

Tags: linux, drivers, arm

I'm working on the StarterKit-5 equipped with a Ka-Ro TX28 module.
Operating system is Linux (Yocto). 
Everything is working great so far, except the i2c0 bus.

When using the **i2cdetect -y 0** to scan a devices on the i2c bus,
the following message is displayed:

```
$ i2cdetect -y 0
...
mxs-i2c 80058000.i2c: PIO: Failed to send SELECT command!
...
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I’m sure everything is connected correctly and the hardware is OK... But nevertheless I can work with it...